# logging of message details in activemq with camel

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, fuseesb

I want to log message details that are going into activemq queue and the response message coming to the queue (queue's exchange pattern is inOut). Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ has plugins and interceptors. So you can also configure this generally on the broker, using the logging interceptors. Some details here: http://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use log4j and also refer Apache-camel log options.

[how do i enable debug logging](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-enable-debug-logging.html), [Log Component](http://camel.apache.org/log.html)   and also [LogEIP](http://camel.apache.org/logeip.html)